# Join table in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

i have a problem using cakephp3 , i have 3 table users(user_id,username, password,email) ,posts(post_id, user_id, content_post) and Comment(comment_id, user_id,post_id ) how I join 3 table using query in cakePHp3 thank u.

Comment: Use MySQL query to join tables.

Comment: oh I using cakePHP, this don't like MySQL :")

Comment: Where do you have the details of the users?

Comment: Can you please provide DB sturcture and result what you are looking for?

Comment: Try reading the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sample query,

```
$GroupAccountIds = $this->ClientForm->find(
'list',
[
    'joins' => [
        [
            'table'=>'group_accounts',
            'alias' => 'GroupAccount',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => [
                'ClientForm.created_group_account_id = GroupAccount.group_account_id',
                'ClientForm.deleted IS NULL'
            ]
        ],
    ],
    'conditions' => [
        'GroupAccount.group_account_category_id' => $smsfCategoryId,
        'GroupAccount.deleted' => null,
    ],
    'fields' => [
        'ClientForm.created_group_account_id',
        'ClientForm.created_group_account_id',
    ],
]
```

);